# Where is the REST API for ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

We test Apache Artemis. We actual use ActiveMQ 5.x

We send messages from our Software to the broker like the URI:
`localhost:8161/api/message/QueueName` with a POST-Request, but this doesn't work in Artemis. I looked around but I didn't find how it should be in Artemis.

Do you know how we can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation for the REST interface](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/rest.html), the default broker doesn't deploy the necessary HTTP endpoints. You'll need to configure and deploy the REST interface as described in the documentation.

That said, the REST interface in ActiveMQ Artemis is different from the one in ActiveMQ 5.x. The two are not compatible.

Comment: Thank you. Somewhere I read, it is possible to change from MQ to Artemis without Problems, if no special configuration is available

Comment: That's true for a lot of use-cases, but it's not true for REST. I would consider REST a "special configuration" because it is not used very commonly compared to the standardized messaging protocols & APIs (e.g. AMQP, STOMP, MQTT, JMS, etc.).